# Can I stop a post back by using javascripts confirm?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, confirm

I have an aspx page with a asp.net button on the page:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Delete" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Delete_Click" OnClientClick="ConfirmDelete();" Text="Delete" />
```

Confirm delete looks like this:

```
   function ConfirmDelete() {
       var answer = confirm("Are you SURE you want to delete this item?");
       if (!answer) {
           return false;
       }
   };
```

I had assumed that this would prevent the page from posting back if the user clicked cancel, but it still appears to be posting back.  Is there some way I can prevent postback using confirm?

Comment: just `OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure?")'` is enough

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to return the value from the function in the event handler:

```
OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete();"
```

By the way, you don't need all that logic in the function, just return the result from the `confirm` call:

```
function ConfirmDelete() {
  return confirm("Are you SURE you want to delete this item?");
};
```