# Javascript confirm window no postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a page where I have created Javascript popup windows that offer confirm scripts on postback for example I have this in the page load

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestDnnPluginsRegistration();
string eventTarget = (this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
string eventArgument = (this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == null) ? string.Empty : this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
cancelSelected = btnCancel_Click_Confirmed(eventTarget, eventArgument);
```

and this method called for a cancel selected

```
        protected const string cancelScriptKey = "CancelScript";
        protected void Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), cancelScriptKey, CoachTeamRegister.BuildConfirmScript("Are you sure you want to cancel?\nAll unsaved changes would be lost?", cancelScriptKey), true);
        }
```

In this case this works because I can finish the operation using the variable cancelSelected in PageLoad

Later in the code though I need to do this process internally in a method without posting back until the method is completed. Is there a way to create a confirm dialog and receive the boolean value from the selection without posting back?

The closest I could find is this [Can I stop a post back by using javascripts confirm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457982/can-i-stop-a-post-back-by-using-javascripts-confirm) which discusses an static button on the page that I already know how to utilize, the customer wants a situation specific dialog box

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know to block the execution is to use the default confirm, which will block the execution until a result is received from the dialog. This not the case when using custom dialog like JQuery. A workaround to achieve that is by executing a server side method through JS based on the result you've got from the dialog, using `__DoPostBack` or `document.getElementById('btnId').click();`

Suppose you have this button in your markup

```
<asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
```

Call your server side event based on the result.

```
     <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Save": function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 //Save was clicked. Call the server side event.
                 document.getElementById('btnSave clientId').click(); 
                 //Or alternatively __DoPostBack('btnSave clientId','');
            },
            Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                //Show message for the user if needed.
            }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```